# Formatting multi-value SSRS Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to pass in multiple values to a query via SSRS.  They are IDs without leading zeros.  I want to add the leading zeros so that the total digits in the ID is 7. (87886,88352) becomes (0087886,0088352).  I had the idea to use a cursor or put it into a temp table, but no matter what I think to do, I run into the same issue where there's just not much I can do with a list of IDs.  No matter what I try, at some point I'm going to need to deal with the list dynamically.  Either dynamically appending the zeros, counting the values, or adding them as rows to a table.  In any case, I'm just not sure how to deal with a list from SSRS in this fashion.

```
SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE ID IN (RIGHT('0000000' + @pIDs,7))
```

That's the idea I'm going for, where @pIDs is a list from SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the leading zeros from the data instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM PERSON 
WHERE -1 < CHARINDEX(',' + CAST(CAST(ID AS INT) AS VARCHAR(7)) + ',', ','+@pIds+',')
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't follow how this works.  I see that you're casting each individual value as an int to remove the leading zeros, but I do not follow how this actually parses out each value separately.  By the comma index somehow?

Answer (score 0):

First, notice that the data type of:

```
RIGHT('0000000' + @pIDs,7)
```

is integer. Your ID column may not be of int type, because you see them in the '0087886' format.

Second, notice that, e.g.

```
select RIGHT('0000000' + 14,7)
```

returns 14 not 0000014.